# Ask users to fill in required custom attributes?

Tags: google-workspace-for-business, g-suite-administrator

We are looking to add custom attributes for our users, like:

- Discord id
- GitHub username
  etc.

I cannot seem to find if there is a way to require these to be filled by users themselves. Have searched for 30 minutes straight with a bunch of different keywords.

Is that even possible? Maybe not with custom attributes but with some other method?

**UPDATE:**

> Are you the domain administrator?

Yes.

> Do you expect that this "custom attributes" appear on the domain directory?

Yes.

> Where do you expect that the users fill the "required custom attributes"

When I as an admin create a new member in our domain and send them the initial details, I'd like that they'd be presented with some form to fill in the required/missing details.

Preferably, also, when a new required field is added and a member does something with their account, just like sometimes they are required to confirm their identity by Google itself asking them to relogin, I would also like them to be asked to fill values for the new attributes that they haven't yet.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please be clear about where do you expect that the users fill the "require custom attributes" and what is your role . Are you the domain administrator? Do you expect that this "custom attributes" appear on the domain directory?

Comment: @Rubén, good questions, updated the post.

Comment: This question has been bumped by Community User 7 times.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the Google Workspace built-in features doesn't support all the things that you are looking for:

- It's possible to allow user to update their directory information
- It's possible to add custom attributes
- but the docs that I reviewed doesn't mention that custom attributes could be edited by the domain users. If you are allowed "to play" with your domain settings, please do it and share your findings.

In case that playing with your domain settings is not possible it's very likely that might be possible to achieve your goal by using a third-party app listed in the Google Workspace Marketplace and by using the Admin Directory SDK. One "simple way" to use the Admin Directory SDK to automate a workflow that allows your users to update their directory information is by using Google Apps Script, you might achieve a high level of automation by setting up a service account with domain-wide delegation of authority.

Resources

- [Create custom attributes for user profiles](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6208725?hl=en)
- [Add information to a user’s Directory profile](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6191788?hl=en)
- [Overview: Set up and manage the Directory](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1628009?hl=en)
- [Admin SDK Directory Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-directory)
- [Perform Google Workspace Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation)